# ResumptionCookie not in MS BotFramework v4

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am porting some code into the newer Microsoft Bot Framework V4 using C#.

The original code was a POC in v3 (still c# though).

I am trying to copy the authentication aspect whereby the user us redirected using a signin card to their bespoke (personal) login page external to the bot. Upon logging in there they are issued a refresh token via our external software, which is then sent via a POST request back to the a controller in the bot, which resumes the conversation (I think this is now referred to as direct line?).

This refresh token is then used to call our api and access data via dialogs.

The state of the conversation I can see is stored in a ResumptionCookie which seems to be part of the BotFramework v3. I understand the sequence but can't seem to locate a ResumptionCookie in v4, nor can I find any examples that I can match to this need.

I was wondering if any core concepts have changed with this regard, or simply the name of the cookie etc.

I'm very new to the framework which has made it slightly more confusing. Unfortunately it feels like the auth is the hardest and first part though!

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ResumptionCookie** has been replaced with **ConversationReference**.

Also, **Azure Bot Service** now provides an OAuth Service configurable from within the Bot Settings:

[image]

Using the Azure Bot Service OAuth with the OAuthPrompt, Bot Service will retrieve the token for you, and simplify the process of authenticating.

More information can be found here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication

A blog post announcing this feature can be found here: 
https://blog.botframework.com/2018/08/28/sign-in-experiences/

Comment: Thanks Eric, I love the idea of using the OAuth prompt and managing the tokens in Azure. However I'm not sure it will be flexible enough for our needs as we have maybe a bit of an unusual setup. A user may authenticate via our site using local username/pass or SAML - also the url for authenticating will be different per tenant as they have their own domains. I can create a process to return a bearer token etc, but is it possible to hook it up this way using the connections you mentioned? Is that what the OAuth2 Generic Provider is for, i.e. the Authorisation Url Template? Many thanks

Comment: Following on from that comment, is there any documentation you're aware of for the Oauth 2 Generic Provider connection service provider?

Comment: I don't know of documentation specific for the OAuth 2 Generic Provider, but it should work with your internal/custom OAuth provider as long as your provider is following the OAuth 2 spec.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I can't understand the format of the available fields for the connection. Looking back into sending the conversationreference data and continuing after visiting out website to login, what would be the approach to sending an activity back to the bot from our website? Would it be using the Bot Connector API?

Comment: You can make a different endpoint in the bot code, and call it after the authentication piece is finished.  This code is a V3 example: https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/botauth/blob/master/CSharp/BotAuth/Controllers/CallbackController.cs#L36 But you can also do something similar in Bot Builder V4.

Comment: Thanks, still trying. I'm not sure what the alternative is now for the Post method which seems used to be on a controller, presumably to allow external input - which is what I need. I've been playing around with the bot connector sdk. Would it be possible to utilise the connector sdk in our main site and send an activity to the bot this way? Just wanted to check I'm not barking up the wrong tree.

I couldn't seem to get my bot to accept an external request when I made a custom callback controller.

Comment: Yes, you can use the connector api to send your bot activities.

Comment: The first line answered my question: ConversationReference is now used instead of resumption cookie. You can Json serialise + encode it and pass it as a querystring as state.

I just fount this repo which is a good reference of someone who has created some auth middleware and good extensions: https://github.com/jamesemann/JamesMann.BotFramework

Comment: Not sure if you also know about a
TurnContext.Services property change?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55445338/iturncontext-service-collection-missing-in-microsoft-bot-builder-4-2-2