# ITurnContext Service collection missing in Microsoft bot builder 4.2.2

Tags: botframework

I'm trying to add some middleware code to a bot I'm creating with microsoft bot framework v 4.2.2.

I can see in previous versions of builder, you're able to add services to the service collection within the 'Services' property of ITurnContext, however it no longer is present, and I can't find any documentation to detail the removal.

```cs
public async Task OnTurn(ITurnContext context, MiddlewareSet.NextDelegate next)
{
    // some middleware method in bot builder 4.0
    context.Services.Add(SOME_KEY, someTService);
    await next();
}
```

I'd like to be doing the same thing with my bot, so if anyone knows where this might have got to I'd much appreciate the info!

Thanks

Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been moved to a property called TurnState;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.turncontext.turnstate

So the code would look like the following;

```cs
public async Task OnTurn(ITurnContext context, MiddlewareSet.NextDelegate next,  CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
{
    // some middleware method in bot builder 4.2.2
    context.TurnState.Add(SOME_KEY, someTService);
    await next();
}
```